# Why are my error messages defined on a schema static method not showing up even though the error handling is apparently working?

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose, error-handling, mongoose-schema

I've defined a static method on the schema that is defining the structure of User documents in my mongodb database. The method `.findByCredentials()` checks if a user-provided email and password match an existing user and (hashed) password in the database. In the event that the `user` cannot be found by the method, an error is thrown. The same is done if a user is found but `bcrypt.compare()` returns `false` (i.e., the provided password does not match what's stored in the DB).  I'm using Mongoose and Express.

The problem I'm having is that the error messages I've defined are not being passed to my Express route - but the `.catch()` statement I have for handling errors IS firing when I pass bad credentials to the route (and therefore the middleware function).  I can update the `res.status()` and I can get a console log from the `.catch()` statement but I can't get the errors I defined in the middleware to show up.  Please forgive my... imprecise description - I'm relatively new to backend and servers so I'm still figuring out how to describe what I'm running into.

I've tried to define the `message` property on the Error by doing something like:

```
throw new Error({ message: "Some message goes here" })
```

and then modifying the `.catch()` in my Express route as follows:

```
.catch (error) {
  res.status(400)
  res.send(error.message)
}
```

In its current state, the Express route has a console log that fires if an error exists - and the console log IS showing up in my console. But in Postman, the `res.send(error)` just shows an empty object. My Express application IS configured to parse JSON (`app.use(express.json())`) so I've also tried to play around with parsing the error but I've had no luck with that either.

Express Route:

```
router.post('/users/login', async (req, res) => {
  const _email = req.body.email
  const _password = req.body.password

  try {
    const user = await User.findByCredentials(_email, _password)
    res.send(user)
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400)
    if (error) {
      console.log("THERES An ERROR")  // THIS CONSOLE LOG IS FIRING
      res.send(error)
    }
  }
})
```

Middleware (defined on a fairly stereotypical User schema)

```
serSchema.statics.findByCredentials = async function (email, password) {
  const user = await User.findOne({ email })

  if (!user) {
    throw new Error({ message: 'Unable to log in. Please check credentials and try again.' })
  }

  const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)

  if (!isMatch) {
    throw new Error({ message: 'Unable to log in. Please check credentials and try again.' })
  }

  return user
}
```

The desired outcome is just for me to access the error messages I defined in the static method. It's not essential to the way the application is running - this is definitely for my own edification. Again, as best I can tell, everything is working in terms of what the middleware is actually supposed to do - which is return a user document from the DB when a provided email address and password match what's stored in the database.  I just have no error messages and for the time being, I want to be able to see if the given email address or password is incorrect (though I understand that this might present a security concern in a real application).

Answer (score 2):

So one possible workaround I found is here: 
https://humanwhocodes.com/blog/2009/03/10/the-art-of-throwing-javascript-errors-part-2/

(From the blog post: )

```js
function MyError(message){
    this.message = message;
}

MyError.prototype = new Error();
```

And in my specific case, as shown in the question above:

```js
userSchema.statics.findByCredentials = async function (email, password) {
  const user = await User.findOne({ email })
  function myError(message) {
    this.message = message
  }

  myError.prototype = new Error()

  if (!user) {
    console.log('Provide a user, you doofus')
    throw new myError('Unable to log in. Please check credentials and try again.')
  }

  const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)

  if (!isMatch) {
    console.log('Password does not match, learn how to type')
    throw new Error('Unable to log in. Please check credentials and try again.')
  }

  return user
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `await` from the

```js
const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)
```

And everything is going to be just fine.
I had that error and I have been searching this for a 2 3 days but eventually removing await really worked.

Comment: this is helpful but why wont it work with await

Comment: That's still what I have to figure out!

Answer (score 0):

Check your model password field maybe you have a lowercase: true property, and also if you use `throw new Error('error message')` in your route catch you need to send it like JSON. Ex.

```
res.json({error: e.message})
```